# Synthesised init for a struct with @propertyWrapper members

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

What's the magic attached to SwiftUI's `@State` property wrapper which means I can I do this?:

```swift
struct A {    
    @State var s: String
}

let a = A(s: "string") //uses a synthesised init for `A` which allows me to init A with the underlying type of `A.s` - a `string`
```

whereas if I roll my own `@propertyWrapper`, I can't?

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct Prop<Value> {
    var value: Value
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }
}

struct B {
    @Prop var s: String
}

let b = B(s: "string") // Compiler error: `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Prop<String>'`
let b = B(s: Prop(value: "string")) // Works, but is ugly
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented in:

- [Swift evolution proposals](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#initialization-of-synthesized-storage-properties)
- [Deep in the language guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID618)

... you **can** get the compiler to do this for you, as it does with `@State` - just add a specific magic `init(wrappedValue:)` to your property wrapper definition:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct Prop<Value> {
    var value: Value
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }

    // magic sauce
    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        self.value = wrappedValue
    }
}

struct B {
    @Prop var s: String
}

let b = B(s: "string") // Now works
```

Incidentally, this also allows you to assign default values for your wrapped properties in the struct definition:

```swift
struct B {
    @Prop var s: String = "default value" // Works now; would have thrown a compiler error before
}
```

Comment: Documented [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md)

Comment: looks like setter is never called in this way.  I fixed it by having following lines in 
 init fuction self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue